# Error while copying cert into cert store server 2008 R2

Tags: powershell, ssl-certificate, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a powershell script written to import certs into the cert store on a server 2008 r2 machine. But I am getting an error that I don't understand and nothing really shows up online for it.

```
Copy-Item $file.FullName  –Destination  $PublicCert
```

`$PublicCert` is `CERT:\LocalMachine\TrustedPeople` and `$File.FullName` is the full path and name of the cert file that resides on the server. The error I get is:

```
Copy-Item : Source and destination path did not resolve to the same provider
```

I don't really understand what it means by "same provider"

Comment: One is a file path and one is a cert path. They do not translate into each other. It saying you are mixing path types

Comment: OK. I guess Copy-Item can't handle this. I altered it to use certutil and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerShell, a *drive*, such as (`C:`, `D:` or `Cert:`) is not necessarily a *FileSystem* drive.

`cert:` for example is a drive representing the certificate store (which is not itself a filesystem).

This object mapping is facilitated by a *Provider* - you can see what Provider provides access to a certain drive with `Get-PSDrive`.

You cannot copy items across drives with different providers - naturally - the Certificate Store doesn't "understand" the concept of a File, which is an item type you would usually find in a Filesystem drive.

See [`Get-Help about_Providers`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847791.aspx) for more info in general

See `Get-Help Certificate` or [`Get-Help FileSystem`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847764.aspx) for the providers for the two drives you're trying to copy between